# Uploading pictures, but I can not delete

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

So you can understand my English is not very good, but to tell you I'm sorry for this situation to work

I am using the version of jQuery 5,11,2

servere, but I can not delete the file uploading

chrome network in the application / json should write text / html writes

I believe that you'll going help you add files Thank you in advance.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../../mysqlayar.php';
include '../../incl/functions.php';


error_reporting(1);

require('upload.class.php');

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();

header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="files.json"');
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-File-Name, X-File-Type, X-File-Size');

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'OPTIONS':
        break;
    case 'HEAD':
    case 'GET':
        $upload_handler->get();
        break;
    case 'POST':
        if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
            $upload_handler->delete();
        } else {
            $upload_handler->post();
        }
        break;
    case 'DELETE':
        $upload_handler->delete();
        break;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
}
```

resim.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
   <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Resim Ekle...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Yükle</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>İptal Et</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Sil</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress information -->
            <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
    </form>
    <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="#" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="#" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/locale.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="scripts/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

upload.class.php

```
<?php

  error_reporting(1);
class UploadHandler
{
    protected $options;

    function __construct($options=null) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
            'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/'.$_SESSION['ilanId']."/",
            'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/'.$_SESSION['ilanId']."/",
            'param_name' => 'files',
            // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
            // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
            'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
            // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
            // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
            'max_file_size' => null,
            'min_file_size' => 1,
            'accept_file_types' => '/.+$/i',
            // The maximum number of files for the upload directory:
            'max_number_of_files' => null,
            // Image resolution restrictions:
            'max_width' => null,
            'max_height' => null,
            'min_width' => 1,
            'min_height' => 1,
            // Set the following option to false to enable resumable uploads:
            'discard_aborted_uploads' => true,
            // Set to true to rotate images based on EXIF meta data, if available:
            'orient_image' => false,
            'image_versions' => array(
                // Uncomment the following version to restrict the size of
                // uploaded images. You can also add additional versions with
                // their own upload directories:
                /*
                'large' => array(
                    'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
                    'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
                    'max_width' => 1920,
                    'max_height' => 1200,
                    'jpeg_quality' => 95
                ),
                */
                'thumbnail' => array(
                    'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/thumbnails/'.$_SESSION['ilanId']."/",
                    'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/thumbnails/'.$_SESSION['ilanId']."/",
                    'max_width' => 114,
                    'max_height' => 114
                )
            )
        );
        if ($options) {
            $this->options = array_replace_recursive($this->options, $options);
        }
    }

    protected function getFullUrl() {
        $https = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off';
        return
            ($https ? 'https://' : 'http://').
            (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].'@' : '').
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].
            ($https && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 443 ||
            $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 80 ? '' : ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']))).
            substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/'));
    }

    protected function set_file_delete_url($file) {
        $file->delete_url = $this->options['script_url']
            .'?file='.rawurlencode($file->name);
        $file->delete_type = $this->options['delete_type'];
        if ($file->delete_type !== 'DELETE') {
            $file->delete_url .= '&_method=DELETE';
        }
    }

    protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.') {
            $file = new stdClass();
            $file->name = $file_name;
            $file->size = filesize($file_path);
            $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                if (is_file($options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
                    $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                        .rawurlencode($file->name);
                }
            }
            $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
            return $file;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected function get_file_objects() {
        return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
            array($this, 'get_file_object'),
            scandir($this->options['upload_dir'])
        )));
    }

    protected function create_scaled_image($file_name, $options) {
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        $new_file_path = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
        if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
            return false;
        }
        $scale = min(
            $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
            $options['max_height'] / $img_height
        );
        if ($scale >= 1) {
            if ($file_path !== $new_file_path) {
                return copy($file_path, $new_file_path);
            }
            return true;
        }
        $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
        $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
        $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
                $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
                    $options['jpeg_quality'] : 100;
                break;
            case 'gif':
                @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
                $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagegif';
                $image_quality = null;
                break;
            case 'png':
                @imagecolortransparent($new_img, @imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
                @imagealphablending($new_img, false);
                @imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
                $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
                $write_image = 'imagepng';
                $image_quality = isset($options['png_quality']) ?
                    $options['png_quality'] : 100;
                break;
            default:
                $src_img = null;
        }
        $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
            $new_img,
            $src_img,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            $new_width,
            $new_height,
            $img_width,
            $img_height
        ) && $write_image($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
        // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
        @imagedestroy($src_img);
        @imagedestroy($new_img);
        return $success;
    }

    protected function validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index) {
        if ($error) {
            $file->error = $error;
            return false;
        }
        if (!$file->name) {
            $file->error = 'missingFileName';
            return false;
        }
        if (!preg_match($this->options['accept_file_types'], $file->name)) {
            $file->error = 'acceptFileTypes';
            return false;
        }
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            $file_size = filesize($uploaded_file);
        } else {
            $file_size = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
        }
        if ($this->options['max_file_size'] && (
                $file_size > $this->options['max_file_size'] ||
                $file->size > $this->options['max_file_size'])
            ) {
            $file->error = 'maxFileSize';
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->options['min_file_size'] &&
            $file_size < $this->options['min_file_size']) {
            $file->error = 'minFileSize';
            return false;
        }
        if (is_int($this->options['max_number_of_files']) && (
                count($this->get_file_objects()) >= $this->options['max_number_of_files'])
            ) {
            $file->error = 'maxNumberOfFiles';
            return false;
        }
        list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($uploaded_file);
        if (is_int($img_width)) {
            if ($this->options['max_width'] && $img_width > $this->options['max_width'] ||
                    $this->options['max_height'] && $img_height > $this->options['max_height']) {
                $file->error = 'maxResolution';
                return false;
            }
            if ($this->options['min_width'] && $img_width < $this->options['min_width'] ||
                    $this->options['min_height'] && $img_height < $this->options['min_height']) {
                $file->error = 'minResolution';
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function upcount_name_callback($matches) {
        $index = isset($matches[1]) ? intval($matches[1]) + 1 : 1;
        $ext = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';
        return ' ('.$index.')'.$ext;
    }

    protected function upcount_name($name) {
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?:(?: \(([\d]+)\))?(\.[^.]+))?$/',
            array($this, 'upcount_name_callback'),
            $name,
            1
        );
    }

    protected function trim_file_name($name, $type, $index) {
        // Remove path information and dots around the filename, to prevent uploading
        // into different directories or replacing hidden system files.
        // Also remove control characters and spaces (\x00..\x20) around the filename:
        $t = explode(".",$name);
        @$name = date('i_s_u_u').".$t[1]";
        $file_name = trim(basename(stripslashes($name)), ".\x00..\x20");
        // Add missing file extension for known image types:
        if (strpos($file_name, '.') === false &&
            preg_match('/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)/', $type, $matches)) {
            $file_name .= '.'.$matches[1];
        }
        if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
            while(is_file($this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name)) {
                $file_name = $this->upcount_name($file_name);
            }
        }
        return $file_name;
    }

    protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        // Handle form data, e.g. $_REQUEST['description'][$index]
    }

    protected function orient_image($file_path) {
        $exif = @exif_read_data($file_path);
        if ($exif === false) {
            return false;
        }
        $orientation = intval(@$exif['Orientation']);
        if (!in_array($orientation, array(3, 6, 8))) {
            return false;
        }
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
        switch ($orientation) {
              case 3:
                $image = @imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
                break;
              case 6:
                $image = @imagerotate($image, 270, 0);
                break;
              case 8:
                $image = @imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        $success = imagejpeg($image, $file_path);
        // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
        @imagedestroy($image);
        return $success;
    }


    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index = null) {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $this->trim_file_name($name, $type, $index);
        $file->size = intval($size);
        $file->type = $type;
        if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
            $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
            $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file->name;
            $append_file = !$this->options['discard_aborted_uploads'] &&
                is_file($file_path) && $file->size > filesize($file_path);
            clearstatcache();
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                if ($append_file) {
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND
                    );
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                    $resimadi = explode("files/",$file_path);
                    $ilanId = $_SESSION['ilanId'];
                    $resimadi = explode("/",$resimadi[1]);
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO resimler VALUES (\"\",
                                                              \"$ilanId\",
                                                              \"$resimadi[1]\")");
                }
            } else {
                // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                    $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                );
            }
            $file_size = filesize($file_path);
            if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                if ($this->options['orient_image']) {
                    $this->orient_image($file_path);
                }
                $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
                foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                    if ($this->create_scaled_image($file->name, $options)) {
                        if ($this->options['upload_dir'] !== $options['upload_dir']) {
                            $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                                .rawurlencode($file->name);
                        } else {
                            clearstatcache();
                            $file_size = filesize($file_path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                unlink($file_path);
                $file->error = 'abort';
            }
            $file->size = $file_size;
            $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
        }
        return $file;
    }

    public function get() {
        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        if ($file_name) {
            $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
        } else {
            $info = $this->get_file_objects();
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($info);
    }

    public function post() {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
            return $this->delete();
        }
        $upload = isset($_FILES[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
            $_FILES[$this->options['param_name']] : null;
        $info = array();
        if ($upload && is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
            // param_name is an array identifier like "files[]",
            // $_FILES is a multi-dimensional array:
            foreach ($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
                $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                    $upload['tmp_name'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : $upload['name'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : $upload['size'][$index],
                    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : $upload['type'][$index],
                    $upload['error'][$index],
                    $index
                );
            }
        } elseif ($upload || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'])) {
            // param_name is a single object identifier like "file",
            // $_FILES is a one-dimensional array:
            $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                isset($upload['tmp_name']) ? $upload['tmp_name'] : null,
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'] : (isset($upload['name']) ?
                        $upload['name'] : null),
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'] : (isset($upload['size']) ?
                        $upload['size'] : null),
                isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']) ?
                    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'] : (isset($upload['type']) ?
                        $upload['type'] : null),
                isset($upload['error']) ? $upload['error'] : null
            );
        }
        header('Vary: Accept');
        $json = json_encode($info);
        $redirect = isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) ?
            stripslashes($_REQUEST['redirect']) : null;
        if ($redirect) {
            header('Location: '.sprintf($redirect, rawurlencode($json)));
            return;
        }
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) &&
            (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json') !== false)) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
        } else {
            header('Content-type: text/plain');
        }
        echo $json;
    }

    public function delete() {
        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(stripslashes($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
        $success = is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.' && unlink($file_path);
        if ($success) {
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                $file = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
                if (is_file($file)) {
                    unlink($file);
                    $ilanId = $_SESSION['ilanId'];

                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM resimler WHERE ilanId = '$ilanId' and resimadi = '$file_name'");
                }
            }
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($success);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you help